# Remove elements from list less than a value after findall

Tags: list, prolog

I have:

```
mymake(Answer_Max):-
    findall((Place, Cost), costOfLiving(Place, Cost), ResultList),
    delete_over(ResultList, Answer_Max).
```

`costOfLiving` is in my database and is formed by each place and cost for example:

```
costOfLiving(germany, 500).
costOfLiving(france, 500).
```

and so on. So that `ResultList` is like `[(germany, 500), (france, 500), ...]`

I would like to delete all of the elements of the database which `costOfLiving` is over the number `Answer_Max`, but my delete_over is not working properly. It is like this:

```
delete_over([], _).
delete_over([F|T], Max) :-
   F =.. [Place, Cost], % it fails here because the F is not a list, but two atoms I think
   ((id_state(Place), (Cost > Max)) -> deleteState(Place) ; true),
   % id_state and id_region checks that the place is defined in the database
   % deleteState and deleteRegion calls a specific retractall for the database
   ((id_region(Place), (Cost > Max)) -> deleteRegion(Place) ; true),
   delete_over(T).
```

How could I solve it to get what I want? (also in case something else is wrong)

---

**EDITED WITH MY SOLUTION** *(and with help)*

```
mymake(Answer_Max) :-   % I don't need the ResultList, but if needed just add as second parameter
    findall( (Place, Cost), ( costOfLiving(Place, Cost), Cost > Answer_Max ), ResultList ),
    maketolist(ResultList).

maketolist([]).
maketolist([(P,_)|T]) :- % all the elements are for deleting as their Cost is higher than the Max given
    (id_state(P) -> deleteState(P) ; true), % deleteState makes a retractall according to my needs on my database 
    (id_region(P) -> deleteRegion(P); true), % the same for deleteRegion with regions
    maketolist(T).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could filter results just in `findall/3`. Btw, `mymake` should have second argument for answer.

```
costOfLiving(germany, 500). 
costOfLiving(france, 500).

mymake(Answer_Max, ResultList) :-
    findall( (Place, Cost)
           , ( costOfLiving(Place, Cost)
             , Cost >= Answer_Max
             )
           , ResultList
           ).
```

And finally:

```
?- mymake(100,X).
X = [ (germany, 500), (france, 500)].

?- mymake(600,X).
X = [].
```

Comment: thanks for that findall, that way I don't have to compare the Costs again, but I didn't wanted a list in return as second parameter. I only wanted to retractall the specific places according to that result list in my database. I edit the question with my final way of doing it, using your findall solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could directly retract from DB, without building a list, but in case you need this structure here is the required correction:

```
delete_over([F|T], Max) :-
   F = (Place, Cost), ...
```

Comment: yes, I was wrong using F =.. [Place, Cost], so I corrected to ([(P,C)|T]) which is just that. thanks